# Does Brave support accessibility APIs on Linux (ATK, AT-SPI)?

Tags: linux, gnome, browser, accessibility

In order for assistive technologies to work with browsers and other applications, these applications need to support the operating system's accessibility API. On the Gnome desktop, the most relevant one are [ATK and AT-SPI](https://developer.gnome.org/accessibility-devel-guide/stable/dev-start-5.html.en).

Firefox has documented its [support for accessibility APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/AT-APIs), which includes ATK/AT-SPI on Linux (in addition to APIs for Windows and Mac OS).

For Brave, I can't find anything similar. There have been a few (well, very few) questions about accessibility in the Brave community forum, but nothing about accessibility for screen reader users on Linux. Hence my question whether Brave support Linux accessibility APIs (possibly without this being publicly documented).

(One of the responses to [this question](https://community.brave.com/t/serious-accessibility-problems/3338) asks which Windows screen reader the question asker is using, which only makes sense *if* some accessibility API support has been built in, at least on Windows.)

**Update (20.10.2020)**: Almost 2 years after posting this question, I still cannot find evidence on the Brave website that the browser implements accessibility APIs on Linux (or on any operating system). There is a feature request to [(Re)introduce Chromium’s Image Description Feature (for Screen Reader Users)](https://community.brave.com/t/re-introduce-chromiums-image-description-feature-for-screen-reader-users/166900) from 30 September 2020, but it is not clear what operating system the person making the request is using.

Comment: P.S.: There are no tags for `accessibility-api`, `atk` or `at-spi`, which would have been useful for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Since Brave is based on Chromium, it surely works the same here, so I bet you can just

```
ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED=1 brave --force-renderer-accessibility
```

[source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Install_Arch_Linux_with_accessibility_options#Troubleshooting)